# how does jms interact with the underlying database?

Tags: java, database, jms

I understand JMS as depicted by the following diagram:

[image: JMS]
<sub>(source: [techhive.com](http://images.techhive.com/images/idge/imported/article/jvw/2002/10/jw-1025-jms1-100157123-orig.gif))</sub>

Is there any way for me to access the underlying database using JMS or some other thing? Further, the JDBC connections that the JMS server maintains, can I add new connections in it so as to access other databases also and do CRUD operations on them? If yes, how?

Comment: JMS is the protocol for sending and receiving messages. There are plenty of JMS providers. Each JMS provider may store the messages in a different way. You should not access the native Databases for a JMS Provider as it might happen that you make the data inconsistent. Use the standard interface (which are sessions to send and receive messages over queues and subjects)

What do you like to do (if you had access to the database)? Maybe there is another way to do this

Comment: So native databases cannot be accessed?

Comment: Wny do you want to do that?

Comment: @LutzHorn I am trying for an alternative way to access database than the conventional DAL. If I use DAOs to modify databases then I need to create DAOs for every table which is a tedious task. I was thinking if there is a workaround using the JMS as it has all the databases that I want to access for my problem.

Comment: Why do you want to access the database used by the JMS implementation?  What is you use case?

Comment: @LutzHorn There are a few tables in a database for the message queues. I have to move messages from one table to another based on some conditions. I am currently using DAL for it, but in DAL I have to create DAOs for every table in the database. As these tables are directly linked with message queues, we use JMS to publish messages to these queues or equivalently insert a record in the queue table. I was thinking of using JMS only to manipulate the tables as then I would save myself from creating the DAOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get this from?

Normally JMS is used to send messages to queue (or topics). You have message producers that push messages in the queue and message consumers consume them and process it.
In your exemple it seems that you have multiple queues. One for the messages that need to be processed, and one for each client to retrieve the result the processing of its messages.

With JMS Server you don't necessarily have a database behind. Everything can stay in memory, or can be written to files. You will need database server behind only if you configure your JMS server to be persistent (and to assure that even if server/application crash your messages won't be lost). But in that case you will never have to interact with the database. Only the JMS server will and you will interact with the JMS server sending and consuming messages.

Comment: Source: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074634/java-web-development/should-you-go-with-jms-.html 
So there is no way to interact with the database, only JMS can do it internally?

Comment: No there is no way to interact with the database and no reason to do so. When you use a JMS Server you use what the JMS provide you: queues, message to send, message to consumes.
Every server will manage it database differently.
It's like if you said you would access the files or database used to store the emails in an email server. If you use an email server you only talk about email with it you don't try to open and modify it's internal files.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to know if its possible.

Comment: What would you like to do if it was possible?

Comment: @JensBaitinger I have explained it in the last comment of my question.